# About fading of questions and tagging

Tags: discussion, tags

If you think this is more related to StackExchange platform please, consider to move it.

I am building my list of **Interesting Tags**. `borderlands` is one of them. I also play only PC games and therefore I added `pc` too.

Instead I put `xbox-360`, `xbox`, `ps3` and `wii` in the **Ignored Tags**.

Now, this question appear to me in the list of questions **faded**: [In Borderlands, what if my character is past level 50 and then I play without the DLC installed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/in-borderlands-what-if-my-character-is-past-level-50-and-then-i-play-without-the)

It contains `borderlands` and `xbox-360`. Now suppose that this question is **platform-independent**. What should I do to avoid fading of this interesting, for me, question? Should I remove `xbox-360` from the my list of **Ignored Tags**. Or should I add `pc` to the tags of the question?

Comment: It isn't faded. It's _blue and_ faded.

Answer (score 5):

"Ignored" status supercedes "interesting". So as long as any one tag on a question is ignored, it does not matter how many interesting tags are on it. It will be faded.

This does pose something of a problem to this site specifically, for people who use it for consoles, due to the number of cross-console games that might hit both lists. Unfortunately, though, having interesting tags override ignored has been ruled against as [status-bydesign] [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10979/exclusion-inclusion-strategy-with-ignored-interesting-tags).

Comment: It'd be nice if we could select which behavior we get in the preferences page, just like we can choose to totally hide the ignored questions at the moment.

Comment: Not really. So long as any one tag on a question is interesting, it does not matter how many ignored tags are on it. It will have a blue background.

Comment: @badp I can replicate this on Stack Overflow, but mysteriously not here (I can't even get plain interesting to highlight, for some reason). This isn't the behavior that I have seen in the past, though, so it is possible that the behavior has changed.

Comment: [I can get highlight and fade on Gaming too.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1164414/SO/Interestingly%20ignored.png)

Answer (score 2):

It will appear both blue and faded, but if it's a platform-independent question, then remove the [xbox-360](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xbox-360) tag, since console tags are only to be used for questions about platform-specific version differences or about the console itself anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Why not apply your own style sheet to fix this, like the following for Firefox?

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("gaming.stackexchange.com") {
    div.tagged-ignored.tagged-interesting {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
}
```